# HOw to show Video In YouTube using YTPlayer?

Tags: android

Hi I ma using [This Library](https://github.com/JackDinealKIM/youtube-android-player-helper) for my application and initializing all value from Recyclker Adapter. I am getting only sound but not able to see video. Please guide me What I did is here. Its working fine on Activity but not working good in case of Adapoter.

```
else {
                String thumbanil_url = demoModels.getVideo();

                Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
                Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(thumbanil_url);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    value_id = matcher.group();
                    ((DemoViewHolderThird) holder).demoThirdItemInitView.youtubePlayerView.setAutoPlayerHeight(context);
                    ((DemoViewHolderThird) holder).demoThirdItemInitView.youtubePlayerView.initialize("YqwVOWYJSxw", new YoutubePlayerView.YouTubeListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onReady() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStateChange(YoutubePlayerView.STATE state) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPlaybackQualityChange(String arg) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPlaybackRateChange(String arg) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String arg) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onApiChange(String arg) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCurrentSecond(double second) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDuration(double duration) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void logs(String log) {

                        }
                    });


                }
```

Comment: From where you are playing video ? I mean called `youtubePlayerView.play();` ?

Comment: Actually I just applied viewing all instruction on GitHub. I don't have much idea sir so please let me know.

Comment: Post your full adapter code.

Comment: did you try this sample code on github https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/YouTubePlayerActivity ??

Comment: @PriyankPatel actually My Adapter is having so big code so I can't share here.. Above code i Use for playing YouTube urls using Library which I had mention previously.

Comment: @PriyankPatel where should I call youtubePlayerView.play() in above overrided method ?

Comment: play video when player is ready or on button click.

Comment: I did but its only playing sound not showing video

Comment: but if i am using activity then then showing perfectly Video and sound